# Add extra headers when using PAW oAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, paw-app

I am building an app on an existing private api for in house use. This api implements oAuth2 for authentication, but also expects extra custom headers to be send when requesting a token.

When working with PAW I can request a token without a problem by a custom request. But when I want to automate the oAuth token request by using the build in oAuth(thingy) then I can't find a way to send those additional headers.

Where/can I do a feature request to implement adding custom headers in oAuth request?

[Example for adding custom headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dx2N.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, Paw doesn't support yet custom headers for OAuth 2 requests, but that's something planned for a future version of Paw. It's actually one of our top requested features, so we're going to add this quickly. No need to request it anywhere, as it's already planned :) Though you can always contact us at https://paw.cloud/support

Comment: Thanks for the reaction, and i will see forward to it :)